# Graphbuilder with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running graphbuilder with hadoop (single-node). I have followed the tutorial "https://01.org/graphbuilder/documentation/how-run-demo-application". However, when I run the command

```
bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/graphbuilder/target/graphbuilder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop-job.jar com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.demoapps.wikipedia.docwordgraph.TFIDFGraphEnd2End 1 /user/hduser/wiki-input /user/hduser/en-wiki-articles-output ingressCode*
```

I am getting error

```
INFO docwordgraph.CreateWordCountGraph: ========== Creating Graph ================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;)V
    at com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.util.FsUtil.distributedTempClassToClassPath(FsUtil.java:46)
    at com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.job.AbstractPreprocessJob.run(AbstractPreprocessJob.java:111)
    at com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.demoapps.wikipedia.docwordgraph.CreateWordCountGraph.main(CreateWordCountGraph.java:77)
    at com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.demoapps.wikipedia.docwordgraph.TFIDFGraphEnd2End.main(TFIDFGraphEnd2End.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)"
```

Can you please guide me how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using a back level version of hadoop.  Check the version of hadoop that your version of graph builder needs and make sure that's the version you're running.

Comment: you were right... I was using hadoop 0.20.0 but graphbuilder need hadoop 1.0.1 version. but now I am having issue with the data node. When I give chmod 775 permission it gives me error "2014-02-18 18:45:33,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot access storage directory /home/mmalik9/hadoop_data/tmp2
2014-02-18 18:45:33,313 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /home/mmalik9/hadoop_data/tmp2 does not exist."

Comment: And the directory does exist?

Comment: Yes, I have check it, directory exists.